# Clear Textbox with Regular Expression Validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, validation, textbox

I Got a text box with a Regular Expression validator, to validate if my textbox is numeric.

here's the code :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxCls"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="valNumbersOnly" ControlToValidate="txtAmount"
                            SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a numbers only in text box."
                            Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="(^([0-9 ]*|\d*\d{1}?\d*)$)">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

and , if the user accidentally input the wrong data , it'll show the Error Like This :

[image: Error]

and i give the user, a clear function to clear all the textbox : with kind of this function :

```
 Public Sub ClearTextBox(ByVal root As Control)
        For Each ctrl As Control In root.Controls
            ClearTextBox(ctrl)
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text = String.Empty
            End If
        Next ctrl
    End Sub


    Protected Sub btnClr_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClr.Click

        ClearTextBox(Me)
        dropResponse.SelectedIndex = 0
        FillData()

    End Sub
```

but , the amount is not cleared, it still show the error. why it still happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are providing this through another button on the same form it won't ever hit the code-behind.

If you want a button on a validated form that needs to fire regardless of whether the other controls have validated, put it in a separate validation group:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClr" Text="Clear form" OnClick="btnClr_Click" ValidationGroup="unvalidatedControls" />
```

Alternatively, put a validation group on your controls that need validating and also the button that submits the form:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxCls" ValidationGroup="validatedControls"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="valNumbersOnly" ControlToValidate="txtAmount"
                            SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a numbers only in text box."
                            Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="(^([0-9 ]*|\d*\d{1}?\d*)$)"
                            ValidationGroup="validatedControls">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit Form" ValidationGroup="validatedControls" />
```

You could put a `ValidationGroup` attribute on both your clear button and the main form, as long as they're different, the clear button will work just fine.

Some documentation on Validation Groups: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the textbox is contained in a panel or another container control. Only the toplevel controls of a page are available in the controls collection of the page.

I would suggest to change the parameter of the call to ClearTextBox with the correct container control.